# .net Decimal.Parse and Double.Parse behavior

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, .net-3.5

I've recently stumbled upon some unintuitive behaviour of `Decimal.Parse`, I'd like to discuss. The case is at follows.
My program gets number as strings from other program, "scientifically" formatted (it's a black box for me). The strings are parsed using `Decimal.Parse`.

```
Dim Value As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(StrValue, Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Everything was fine, until it tried to parse `"1.9721522630525295e-31"`. On this string Decimal.Parse raises an OverflowException. "Ok," I thought, "let's try Double instead!"

```
Dim dblValue As Double = Double.Parse(StrValue)
```

This works fine. Kind of: the result is `0.0000000000000019721522630525295`. (or: `Double.Parse(StrValue).ToString = "1,97215226305253E-15"`)

Ok, next try.

```
Dim dblValue As Double = Double.Parse(StrValue, Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```

Works as expected, the `E-31` stays that way.

So, this is my **1st question**: why is Double.Parse behaving this way?

**edit** By "this way" I mean giving me a number 16 orders of magnitude greater then expected (`E-15` instead of `E-31`). The question was **answer**ed by varocarbas: the reason is my local decimal and thousands separators settings. The `.` in `"1.9721522630525295e-31"` is treated by `Double.Parse(StrValue)` like thousands separator (i.e. ignored), and thus the Value becames `0.0000000000000019721522630525295`.

Then I did, like I always did before, convert the result to decimal.

```
Dim decValue = CDec(dblValue)
```

No exceptions but the value I got was once again `1.9721522630525295E-15`.
After some google I learned about `Convert.ToDecimal`, which works fine (the `...E-31` is converted to `0`.)

The **2nd question**: shall we always use `Convert.ToDecimal` and never `CDec` or are there some rules or best practices or whatever?

So, after all of that I'm now using the following code.

```
If Not Decimal.TryParse(StrValue, Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, _
                           Value) Then
    Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Double.Parse(StrValue, Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo))
End If
```

My **3rd** and last (for the moment) **question** is: is this code the proper way to do it?

(specs: Visual Studio 2005, .net 3.5, application compiled as 32-bit, Windows locale is set to German.)

Comment: It's really not clear what you mean by "why is Double.Parse behaving this way" - what exactly were you expecting to be different? Are you expecting it to give a different *value*, or were you expecting a call to `ToString` to then give back the original string? Those are *very* different aspects of behaviour.

Comment: Also note that converting a `Double` to a `Decimal` is a bad idea, in general - you may well lose information. Fundamentally, `decimal` can't handle values that close to zero. What are you trying to achieve here? What is the value meant to represent? (At the moment we can't tell which type you *should* be using.)

Comment: Double.Parse(StrValue, Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo) forces "." as the decimal separator. Double.Parse(StrValue) takes the default decimal separator in your system (which seems to be ","). That's why Double.Parse(StrValue) understands your input wrongly. All the methods you propose should behave equivalently under normal conditions (although note that CDec comes from old VB before .NET); accounting for so many decimal positions is certainly not good. Roughly speaking, anything above the number of digits of Decimal.MaxValue is a problem.

Comment: ah, thanks @varocarbas, I get now why there is that 16 order of magnitude difference.

Comment: @JonSkeet My the 1st question was answered by @varocarbas: it's because the decimal separator on my system was "," by default. The expected value of internal double variable is `1.9721522630525295e-31`. The expected value for decimal variable is `0`.